# How to clean modified associations on an active record transaction rollback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

I ran into a bug today in rails that seems slightly unintuitive to me. Basically, after rolling back a transaction, I still had unpersisted models in some associations. I would have assumed that rails clears these on transaction rollback.

Basically my situation was as follows:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :childs
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: parent
end

parent = Parent.first
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  parent.childs.create!({ :title => 'New' })
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end

pp parent.childs

#Here I was expecting parent.childs to be []

#But instead I get [#<Child id: nil>]
```

What I assume is happening here is that create! is a wrapper for Class.new, instance.save.
The rollback undoes the save, but not the new. This throws an exception for me down the line if I call parent.touch or parent.save!

I just want to confirm that my understanding is correct and on rollback we have to manually clean any associations that were edited in the transaction?

Is there any easy way of doing this or do we have to explicitly edit any modified association like this:

```
parent.childs = parent.childs.select{|c| c.persisted? }
```

Also, in the case we have to manually clean up, is there any way to catch the Rollback and perform cleanup in a rescue block, or do we have to wrap the transaction in a method?

Comment: While not an Answer the term "bug" is misused here. The [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) do warn you about this: *"Exceptions will force a ROLLBACK that returns the database to the state before the transaction began. Be aware, though, that the objects will **not** have their instance data returned to their pre-transactional state."* So this is a known functional implementation. Potentially surprising yes but certainly not a bug.

Comment: As another aside if `create!` fails it will raise and the this Exception will trigger the rollback (your explicit `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` will never be reached) but this error `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` will bubble up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rollback only reverts the changes made to the database by opening an SQL transaction and calling `COMMIT` at the end of the block or calling `ROLLBACK` if there is any exception raised within the block.

You are raising `ActiveRecord::Rollback` which is the only exception that is not re-raised outside the transaction method after the rollback. If you want to rescue this exception you have to do it before it gets to the transaction logic and then re-raise it.

```rb
parent = Parent.first
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  parent.childs.create!({ :title => 'New' })
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
rescue StandardError => e
  # here is the last chance to catch ActiveRecord::Rollback
  # however the database changes are not yet reverted. This means
  # that while parent.reload might work, parent.childs.reload will
  # make matters worse because now the child (which will be rolled
  # back later) has an ID and it will respond true to .persisted?
  parent.reload
  raise e
end
```

Usually the rollback event will be triggered by a different exception like `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid`. This exception is then re-reraised after the rollback so you can catch it and reload your model there.

```rb
parent = Parent.first
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    parent.childs.create!({ :title => 'New' })
    raise ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
  end
rescue
  parent.childs.reload
end
```

Comment: One could potentially also leverage the [`after_rollback`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_rollback) hook depending on the actual implementation. (in the naive example it would not make much sense)